# How to obtain indices by specified array in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following array. I want to extract indices by a search key of array.
`np.array([[1,2],[2,2], [3,2], [2,2]])`'s shep is `(4, 2)`. So the result of searching `[2, 2]` should return `[1, 3]` which is an index of `[2, 2]`. `np.argwhere` is a strong function, though, how to use this for my purpose?

```
In [31]: d=np.array([[1,2],[2,2], [3,2], [2,2]])    
In [32]: d
Out[32]:
array([[1, 2],
       [2, 2],
       [3, 2],
       [2, 2]])

In [33]: np.where(d==np.array([2,2]))
Out[33]: (array([0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3]), array([1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]))
In [34]: np.argwhere(d==np.array([2,2]))
Out[34]:
array([[0, 1],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [2, 1],
       [3, 0],
       [3, 1]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `np.all(..., axis=1)` to reduce the boolean array over the second axis, then use `np.where`:

```
np.where((d == [2, 2]).all(1))[0]
# array([1, 3])
```